# rendor_to_response is not defined error in django

Tags: django

This is my views.py code.

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
def index(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    context_dict = {'bold-message': "I am bold font from the context"}
     return render_to_response('rango/index.html', context_dict, context)
```

After starting the project when I run this in server,  I am getting the following exception.

Global name 'rendor_to_response' is not defined

Please tell what I did wrong.

Comment: which version are you using?

Comment: version is 1.11.1

Comment: then i would say use render instead of render_to_response as its outdated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rendor_to_response` is a typo. It should be `render_to_response`.

However, you shouldn't be using `render_to_response` at all. You should use the `render` shortcut instead.

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    context_dict = {'bold-message': "I am bold font from the context"}
    return render(request, 'rango/index.html', context_dict)
```

If you are following a tutorial that is using `render_to_response` then it is out of date. You should switch to an updated version of the tutorial, or a different tutorial.

Comment: The code he posted does not have rendor_to_response so I don't think that's the problem. Typo is in posting the error as far as I understand this thing

Comment: @ArpitSolanki the posted code would not produce a `NameError` since it contains `from django.shortcuts import render_to_response`. The title and the question both contain `rendor` so I think there's a good chance that the actual code is `return rendor_to_response(...)`.

Comment: I am referring to tango with django book. May be I ll refer to some updated tutorial. Thank you.

Comment: @user8220311, the [official tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial01/) is quite good.

Comment: *Tango with Django 1.7*  uses `render` instead of `render_to_response`, so you must be using the 1.5 version. I'm not sure I would recommend *Tango with Django 1.7*, because there were a lot of changes in Django 1.8. Consider switching to the *Tango with Django 1.9/1.10* or a different resource.